# divide header into columns in jquery using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to divide header into three columns for three images. but they overlap.

How do i divide div header into three columns.

This is my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="loginpage" class="loginbody"> 

<div data-role="header" style="background-image:url('images/Login/header_bg.PNG');">

<img id="headerselect" alt="" src="images/Login/.PNG"  class="ui-btn-left"></img>

<img alt="" src="images/Login/.PNG"></img>

<img alt="" src="images/Login/.PNG" class="ui-btn-right"></img>
```

Comment: Please try and reproduce this issue on http://jsfiddle.net and give us the link so we can get a better sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are static (always the same 3 images) the best idea is to fuse all of them so that you have to include only one image. 
If they change from time to time, you could insert 3 divs inside the header, all of them with 'float:left'
Please tell me if you need it explained a little more

Comment: hi.. i added three header with float:left but of no use.. the images still overlap

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: block` to `img` tags in the header, and use `float: left` to make columns.

```
[data-role="header"] img {
 dispaly: block;
 float: left;
}
```

Check the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanz/HDwE2/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great way of positioning any elements in the header:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" id="header" style="background-image:url('images/Login/header_bg.PNG');">

  <ul>
    <li><img id="headerselect" alt="" src="images/Login/.PNG"  class="ui-btn-left" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" src="images/Login/.PNG" /></li>
    <li><img alt="" src="images/Login/.PNG" class="ui-btn-right" /></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#header ul li {
display: inline;
}
```

allows you to position with ease as well!

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DJSrA/4H5qs/